# How can I select two ranges of the same field in Django?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, django-database

With the following model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
```

I would like to execute the following logic:

**Select all events where latitude is in range(float1, float2) or in range (float3, float4)**

This looks like this in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE latitude (BETWEEN float1 and float2) or latitude (BETWEEN float3 and float4);
```

I tried this in Django but I get a "SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated":

```
Events.objects.filter(latitude__range=(float1, float2), latitude__range=(float3, float4)
```

Comment: don't put brackets around `BEWEEN`.  `latitude BETWEEN float1 and float2` is a unique part of the syntax and won't get merged with `or`

Comment: I just do that for legibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## using Q()|Q()

```
from django.db.models import Q
Event.objects.filter(
    Q(latitude__range=(float1,float2)) | Q(latitude__range=(float3,float4))
)
```

## see the document https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to keep better readability as you mentioned:

````
 SELECT * 
 FROM event 
 WHERE (latitude BETWEEN float1 AND float2) 
 OR (latitude BETWEEN float3 AND float4);```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `fieldName` BETWEEN value1 `AND` value2 is unique syntax. And actually you don't need to add parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE latitude BETWEEN float1 and float2 OR 
latitude BETWEEN float3 and float4;
```

if would like to add parentheses for readability, you can add as below:

```
SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE (latitude BETWEEN float1 and float2) OR 
(latitude BETWEEN float3 and float4);
```

Comment: @Rage see if it helps

Comment: Thanks but the question asks for a Django ORM query.